# Paramiko Script for SSH and VNC

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to write a script to use when connecting remotely to various computers in my office.  We also use VNC to allow us to see the user desktops.  I have been trying to find a script that would allow me to do this, but I have had no luck.  Right now, we use the SSH command in Terminal (we all use Macs), which looks like the following:

```
ssh "hostname" -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5900
```

This then requires RSA fingerprint and user password.  Username is never requested as it is the same as the user profile on the computer.  5901 can also be 5902, 5903, etc, depending on which display port is specified in our VNC client.

I would ultimately like to created a script that would prompt for hostname and display port, assuming username and password can be stored permanently in the script.  If not, we would need prompts for those as well.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I while ago had a similar use case so I put together this script:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576810-copy-files-over-ssh-using-paramiko/

To tunnel VNC over SSH you would need to forward port 5900 for connecting to the real xorg instance, e.g. via `x11vnc`, or port 5901 to connect to the first virtual xorg (e.g. via `vncserver`), 5902 to connect to the second xorg, etc.

I am not aware of paramiko being able to forward ports but there seems to be a pure Python module that does just that https://gist.github.com/1399529